# My Commute icons

Tags: maps, here

When you pin My Commute as a live tile, it tells you the estimated time of your commute at about the time it knows you want to leave, but, sometimes it shows a tick in the tile, other times it shows an exclamation mark (examples of both below).  Is there a legend for these, or some way of knowing when the commute will have a tick or exclamation mark (or any other symbol?!), such as it has an exclamation mark if it's *n* standard deviations greater than the mean journey time? I know there has to be a cut off / boundary, but in my instance, the difference between 1 hr 22 and 1 hr 24 wouldn't immediately seem to be the difference between 'good' and 'bad'

[image]

[image]

**Further edit**

It appears that the algorithm for suggesting what constitutes a 'delay' isn't the same in both directions - this morning, my phone helpfully told me that a 1 hr 14 journey needed an exclamation mark (so why not the 1 hr 22 journey yesterday?)

[image]

Comment: It probably just means there are delays on the route (ie. heavy traffic, accident, etc)

Comment: @NeilTurner it can't be that simple; my commute should be 55 mins - in this instance I don't really understand how 1 hr 24 can be bad, but 1 hr 22 good? And, to confuse things even more, I've added another scrrenshot

Comment: I wonder if it's comparing the commutes to previous journeys - so the exclamation is for when it's worse than normal conditions for that day, rather than longer than ideal conditions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading [an article on HERE.com](http://360.here.com/2013/07/31/how-to-use-my-commute-on-windows-phone-8/) uses the phrase:

> If other users of HERE Drive are on a busy road and stop for more than would be expected, the mapping servers are notified and this anonymous data is passed onto other users.
>
> If this real-time traffic data coincides with one of your Commutes, the Live tile will notify you that your journey may take longer than usual. It’s then up to you to decide if you need to leave earlier to ensure you arrive at your destination on time.

Going by the phase there "*the Live tile will notify you that your journey **may take longer than usual***", I would believe that the warning is if the commute is likely to take longer than it usually would, rather than longer than ideal situations. By the very nature of how people choose to commute, I would expect a homeward journey to encounter more traffic as everyone leaves together, hence the difference in warning thresholds between home bound and work bound.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that without knowing the actual algorithm used by the software, this is probable the closest we'll get (although FWIW, in my experience, I think morning rush hours are more likely to encounter traffic - things like picking children up from school, leaving early to go out for an evening, staying late to finish a particular job means the evening traffic is more protracted)!